# DocFetcher can't run because it is missing java even though openJDK is installed

Tags: java, jre, openjdk, docfetcher

Problem: I'm trying to run [DocFetcher](https://sourceforge.net/projects/docfetcher/).

[image]

But I do have it installed:

[image]

What do?

Comment: You have 1.8.0_202 installed not 1.7.0.

Comment: You don't say...